# How to adjust settings PHP5 and OCI8 module

Tags: php, oracle

Ubuntu 14.04.3 x64, Apache 2.4.7, nginx 1.9.10, php PHP 5.6.18-1 
I install oracle instantclient and OCI8 extension use [this manual](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/dsl/technote-php-instant-12c-2088811.html), but it is not initialized and `php -i` show me warning

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: oci8: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20121212
PHP    compiled with module API=20131226
These options need to match in Unknown on line 0
```

How to adjust settings PHP5 and OCI8 module? 
Thank in advance.

Answer (score 1):

My solution to **PHP 5.6** was:

run as ROOT:

```
# pecl install oci8-2.0.12
```

then in the question, `select [autodetect]`

After of this, ALL is FINE!